# Position div to center of visible area

Tags: javascript, jquery, centering

I'm in the midst of making a lightbox style pop-up for a mailing list sign up, but I want the pop-up to position to the center of the visible page, not just the center of the whole document; if the user scrolls to the bottom of the page and clicks to sign up, I want it to appear in the center of the screen.

I'm assuming jQuery/JS will be the best way to go for this; here's my current CSS code which works fairly well but the div needs to be pushed down into the visible space dynamically for smaller screens.

```
.my-div{
    width:960px;
    height:540px;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-480px;
    margin-top:-270px;
    z-index:60;
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: @Truth Sorry - it is still early. Not sure where that came from. I have deleted my comment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to center html element in browser window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982054/how-to-center-html-element-in-browser-window)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You were close! It can be done with CSS alone:

Use `position: fixed` instead of `position: absolute`.

Fixed refers to the viewport, while absolute refers to the document. **[Read all about it!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/position)**

Answer (score 9):

```
var w = $(window).width();
var h = $(window).height();
var d = document.getElementById('my-div');
var divW = $(d).width();
var divH = $(d).height();

d.style.position="absolute";
d.style.top = (h/2)-(divH/2)+"px";
d.style.left = (w/2)-(divW/2)+"px";
```

Answer (score 5):

I know this will not solve the question but it is good reference and a starting point: [How to position a div in the center of browser window](http://www.corelangs.com/css/box/center-div.html)

Position Div Exactly at the center of the screen

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
  <html > 
    <head> 
      <style type="text/css"> 
        .exactCenter { 
           width:200px; 
           height:200px; 
           position: fixed; 
           background-color: #00FF00; 
           top: 50%; 
           left: 50%; 
           margin-top: -100px; 
           margin-left: -100px; 
        } 
      </style> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
      <div class="exactCenter"> </div> 
    </body> 
  </html>
```

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/loginet/q2qfrk2x/1/)
and [here](http://jsfiddle.net/loginet/6ky11zgx/)

Answer (score 3):

with jQuery:

```
var left = ($(window).width() - $(.my-div).width()) / 2;
var top = ($(window).height() - $(.my-div).height()) / 2;
$('.my-div').position({top: top + 'px', left: left + 'px});
```

Answer (score 3):

Although the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9062647/4861207) is best, if you can't set the `divs position` to `fixed`, then you can use this pure JavaScript solution.

```
var myElement = document.getElementById('my-div'),
    pageWidth = window.innerWidth,
    pageHeight = window.innerHeight,
    myElementWidth = myElement.offsetWidth,
    myElementHeight = myElement.offsetHeight;

myElement.style.top = (pageHeight / 2) - (myElementHeight / 2) + "px";
myElement.style.left = (pageWidth / 2) - (myElementWidth / 2) + "px";
```

#### JSFiddle

Or a more condensed version:

```
var w = window,
    elem = document.getElementById('my-div');

elem.style.top = (w.innerHeight/2) - (elem.offsetHeight/2) + 'px';
elem.style.left = (w.innerWidth/2) - (elem.offsetWidth/2) + 'px';
```

This answer is a vanilla JavaScript version from [Lahiru Ashan's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12434737/4861207) answer.