# How to center div elements in canvas

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, positioning

I am drawing a canvas with a javascript function and it always aligns to windows size.
I want to have a

```
<div>...</div>
```

Element overlay a canvas and be vertically and horizontically centered.

The only thing I came up was

```
position:absolue;
```

But then again

```
top:0;
left:0;
bottom:0;
right:0;
```

Only centers my element horizontically not vertically.

So I've changed it to.

```
 left:calc(50% - *divwidth*/2);
 top:calc(50% - *divheight*/2);
```

But it is not optimal and doesnt work for various windows sizes.

I think that this might not even be possible with pure css, so I am happy to use JS but how do I do that?

Comment: Try the `vw` and `vh` units instead of percentage.

Comment: @Phix can you give an example? If I change % to vh/vw it still wont center...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flexbox: center horizontally and vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19026884/flexbox-center-horizontally-and-vertically)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried giving the div overlay a `height` and `width` of `100%`?

Answer (score 0):

The answer from [Adrian P.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1058605/adrian-p) in [Position div to center of visible area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9062583/position-div-to-center-of-visible-area) 
worked surprisingly well for my case and a fixed width height div. I will be using this until I find a better one.